# How can I use ubuntu container as a regular server that I can ssh into remotely?

Tags: docker

I just started learning to use docker. My original purpose is to build a development environment image based on ubuntu, so that I can have a consistent development environment when I frequently switching between different machines: company windows PC, company windows laptop, macbook at home...

Now I've built an image FROM ubuntu. But what surprises me is that the container cannot be used as a running machine. When I run `docker run xxxx`, the container just exit immediately due to that I didn't run any service in it.

I found that I can use `docker run -it xxx` to get into `/bin/bash` on the machine and do something. But the container exit immediately I type `exit` in bash.

How can I use an ubuntu image as a long running server, and I can ssh into it from whatever machine I'm current using??

Comment: You can hardly, and actually shoudn't. This is not a regular use case at all and may not be easy to do.

Comment: For your use case, you should use `Vagrant` to create a VM. Docker is not meant to be used like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout the LXD project from canonical, which is attempting to build a full OS capability using containers:

http://www.ubuntu.com/cloud/lxd

Docker, on the other hand, is designed primarily to package and deploy applications.

Comment: thanks a ton, Mark!! It's the exact kind of help I'm seeking. Pointing me to the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Dockers can totally be a long running process, it is designed first for running servers. The issue you are seeing is just because you didn't give it a process in your Dockerfile to run. If you do not then as you saw it will run like a service.

Try doing more of the docker lessons, you just need a CMD at the end to keep it running, like most containers use.